# csrf token verification error (403) when I try to login as admin since I upgraded django from 1.11 to 2.1.1?

Tags: python, django, csrf

It turns out that the problem is only existing in chrome. I guess I have to make some changes in the settings file regarding csrf_tokens but where ? Please help. Here is my code for urls.py in the main application

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import url, include

    urlpatterns = [
        #Admin section url
        url('^admin/', admin.site.urls),

        #Music section url
        url('^music/', include('music.urls')),

    ]
```

And the code for settings.py file in the main application

```
    """
    Django settings for TestMe_App project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '1d!vux17gbzi_ux75mu4h1r+*bd+**b6bjpk9^twk0$z)1z57i'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'music',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'TestMe_App.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
            ,
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TestMe_App.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Everything was going so smooth with django 1.11, but this unexpected error popped out from nowhere when I migrated and I tried many solutions like setting some values for csrf_domain in the settings file. But, none of them worked. Please help!

Code for views.py file in the music app

`from django.shortcuts import render


def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'music/home.html')`

Comment: Can you post your views.py?

Comment: Sure, edited the post now. But it's giving error when I try to access the admin page.